# URI redirection in NGINX

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

This is my first question here.

I have developed a web app in CodeIgniter. It's working fine on ubuntu with apache. But while I upload it to my server it is not working anymore. The server uses NGINX.

I'm removing index.php from URL using .htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I'm not doing this and keeping index.php than it works fine.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The nginx doesn't support `.htaccess`. Write the settings into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

The syntax of the Apache's Rewrite Engine also isn't supported by Nginx.

**Apache**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Same Rewrite for Nginx** (auto converted)

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break;
  }
}
```

- [Converter Apache => Nginx](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess)
- [Nginx Wiki: CodeIgniter Receipt](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/)
- [Nginx Blog: Convert Apache to Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: thanks, I have to do it on server side, not on the local system. How to do that on the server. I didn't find "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" there.

Comment: maybe you can find an file like `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourSite (or default)`

Comment: I find /etc/ but there is nothing like Nginx or other. There are mydomain_name and webdav inside etc.